# How to uniquely identify a computer based on Gmail, Skype and Apple updates

Tags: serial-number

I bought an iMac some time ago. Although it was stolen some time ago, I managed to get the Serial Number from the provider who sold it to me. The point is that I know who took it and also that he is using it.

I have received gmail from him and also Skype. Could I somehow identify that serial number based on those messages?

If not, what about the Apple updates? Do they keep track of the serial numbers and IPs from where the update has been done?

I´ve looked at the different threads here and nobody seems to have an answer to this.

Comment: If you know who took it, can't you just go to the police, right now?

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser too, though Blorgbeard and Cory are probably right.

Comment: Maybe your question would be more relevant at http://superuser.com/

Comment: Blorgbeard and Cory are definitely right. Go to the police, declare the property stolen, identify the suspected thief and provide any evidence you may have to support that. Let the police handle it and don&t get _yourself_ into trouble trying to do the investigation on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you're out of luck.

However, if you've got something credible showing that your buddy stole the machine, you should be able to get the police/judge to allow a very specific search to physically enter his place and check the serial on the box.